# Convert a text into a cstring in PostgreSQL script with C

Tags: c, string, postgresql, text

I am editing a script of postgresql-9.1.3 installation package to implement a function designed by myself. Here I get in 2 text variables. As I need to do some computation upon these strings, I want to convert them into cstrings(char). What should I do next? Thanks!

```
text *str_01=PG_GETARG_DATUM(0);
text *txt_02=PG_GETARG_DATUM(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [text_to_cstring(const text *   t)](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/varlena_8c.html#a7777d194920e57222a17b02166fc7232)

Note that instead of `PG_GETARG_DATUM`, normally `PG_GETARG_TEXT_PP` is recommended if the argument is of text type. Beware of the fact that text values may be toasted/compressed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried ```text_to_cstring``` but when I use my function in the database console, it raises error of sever lost.

Comment: It seems that ```PG_GETARG_TEXT_PP``` fixes the issue!